# How to set a subset with specific category in Fashion_mnist (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

Now i have use orginal data with Fashion_mnist:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/fashion_mnist/load_data

```
fashion_mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images,train_labels),(test_images,test_labels)=fashion_mnist.load_data()
class_names = ['T-shirt/top','Trousers','Pullover','Dress','Coat','Sandals','Shirt','Shirt','Sneakers','Bag','Ankle boot']
```

How can i create a subset with specific category like 6000 T-shirt and 6000 Dress and 1000 in each other category?

Comment: Do you want to save the images somewhere or just load data into 10 different variables?

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet should help you get started with it. `train_data` and `test_data` contain the data of each class (indexed from 0 to 9, equivalent to your `class_names`).

```
import tensorflow as tf

fashion_mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images,train_labels),(test_images,test_labels)=fashion_mnist.load_data()
class_names = ['T-shirt/top','Trousers','Pullover','Dress','Coat','Sandals','Shirt','Shirt','Sneakers','Bag','Ankle boot']

train_data = []; test_data = []
for i in range(10):
    idxs = [idx for idx,item in enumerate(train_labels) if item==i]
    train_data.append(train_images[idxs])

    idxs = [idx for idx,item in enumerate(test_labels) if item==i]
    test_data.append(train_images[idxs])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this loop really help me to find what i need ! but there are also coming out question,The value of "train_images[idxs]" which is a 2darray, how can i save it into a new empty 3darray? how can i create it? i have try many times but it not goona append successfully even with "np.append(new_ndarray,train_images[idx])"

Comment: @AxlHuang, please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  and consider accepting the answer. For new questions, you could create a new post. Make sure you give the right input and output descriptions.